# Inactive button in gridlayout - Nativescript-vue

Tags: nativescript-vue

The following code contains logout button but it's inactive.

```
<DockLayout class="screen" stretchLastChild="true">
<ScrollView dock="top">
    <StackLayout orientation="vertical">
        <GridLayout class="header" rows="auto" columns="*,auto,auto">
            <Label text="$124.57" row="0" col="0" verticalAlignment="center"></Label>
            <Image src="~/assets/images/search.png" verticalAlignment="center" marginRight="25" row="0" col="1" height="22" />
            <!-- <Image src="~/assets/images/header-cart.png" verticalAlignment="middle" marginRight="10" row="0" col="2" height="14" /> -->
            <Button class="logoutButton" text="Logout" fontSize="14" verticalAligment="middle" marginRight="10" row="0" col="2" @tap="logout()"/>
        </GridLayout>
```

service.js: (This method works well in actionbar, so no issue with my settings)

```
logout() {
    return Parse.User.logOut();
}
```

method in vue component:

```
logout() {
      this.$backendService.logout();

      this.$navigateTo(Login, {
        clearHistory: true
      });
    },
```

No css for that class, but when I delete the class from the button, no changes.

Using the same Button element in the action bar, it works flawlessly. Is there any restriction in gridlayout? Button displays as a text, not a button.

Thanks!

Comment: Nop. No on the grid layout. Buttons on the action bar may look different though. Show the `.logoutButton` class and a screenshot of what is happening there.

Comment: Hi Tiago, the description has been updated. Thank you very much. The outcome is logout is not a button, just a simple text.